# Change the cursor focus position inside textfield css

Tags: jquery, html, css

How do I change my text field cursor start position? I want my input cursor to start at the very beginning of my text field. Currently it starts from the middle area.

Here is the css for my text area.

```
  <input id="probleminput" class="form-inline" type="text" style="display: inline;"></input>

   #probleminput {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        top: 448px;
        left: 185px;
        height: 94px;
        width: 370px;
        border: 1px solid;
        outline: none;
        font-size:20px;
        font-family: Verdana;
        background:transparent;
        background-repeat: repeat;
        margin: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
        color: cyan;
    }
```

Can I change something above to make the text cursor focus from the beginning? I hope my question was not ambiguous. Thanks!

Comment: Yes. I am applying it to input. I have edited my question code.

Comment: Currently, everything works fine. I can write text and everything but it starts from the middle of the text area. I want my text input to start from the beginning of the text area.

Comment: try using <textarea> instead of <input> that will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the height, but rather use padding.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9pQyP/)**

```
 #probleminput {
     position: absolute;
     display: none;
     top: 448px;
     left: 185px;
     width: 370px;
     border: 1px solid;
     outline: none;
     font-size:20px;
     font-family: Verdana;
     background:transparent;
     background-repeat: repeat;
     margin: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
     color: cyan;
     padding: 0 0 94px;
 }
```

But on a side note, you probably want a textarea element instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to have more than one line of text in the box, consider using a [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) instead. Input text fields are typically for a single line, which is why it vertically centers your text.

**Edit**: You can keep your CSS the same and make the following HTML changes:

```
<textarea id="probleminput" class="form-inline" style="display: inline;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Great thanks. But how do I get rid of the text area drag icon at the bottom right consisting of triangulated dots? I do not want that.

Also is there a way to modify the scroll bar like is there a way to stylize it and make it look more beautiful instead of the normal grey colored bar

Comment: To disable resizing, add `resize:none;` to your CSS for the textarea. Styling scrollbars is a little trickier; different browsers display scrollbars differently, and there isn't a good way to style them that works in all browsers aside from using a plugin that "fakes" them, such as [perfect-scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/). Another option is making the textarea large enough that nobody will need to scroll and adding `overflow:hidden;` to the CSS, which won't display scrollbars if too much text is entered.